# What is this type of C# coding syntax called and what is it doing?

Tags: c#, syntax, new-operator

For the below code, specifically the `{}` that don't seem connected to anything, what is the syntax called and what is it doing?

And when/why can I omit the `()` when using this syntax?

```
var a = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() // Can I omit () and when/why?
{
    { // What is this doing?
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id="Bearer"
            }
        },
        new string[]{}
    } // What is this doing?
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outermost curly bracket is just a [collection initialiser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers).

The inner curly bracket that "don't seem to be connected to anything" exists because the `Add` method of `OpenApiSecurityRequirement` takes two parameters.

Surely you have seen this syntax with `Dictionary`s:

```
new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "key1", "value1" },
    { "key2", "value2" },
    { "key3", "value3" }
};
```

Assuming [this `OpenApiSecurityRequirement`,](https://github.com/ranul-pallemulle/X13.OpenAPI/blob/750fe4a6db5cb57a5bb677609b81de51bd4a1090/X13.OpenAPI/Public/Model/OpenApiSecurityRequirement.cs) which is also an `IDictionary`, your code is just that, but the inner curly brackets are written on multiple lines. The dictionary has one entry. The key is the `OpenApiSecurityScheme`, and the value is the empty string array.

And yes, the parentheses can be omitted.

Desugared:

```
var a = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement();
a.Add(
    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id="Bearer"
            }
        }, 
    new string[]{}
);
```

Comment: Ah I see! It just looked so odd the way it was typed I didn't realize it was a collection. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

`OpenApiSecurityRequirement` inherits from `Dictionary<OpenApiSecurityScheme, IList<string>>`

Which has a method `public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)`

The second curly brace is just syntactic sugar for calling this `Add` method and passing in any objects you give it.

The parenthesis are unnecessary because if you omit them, the empty constructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, this is what a minimal implementation of the pattern looks like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Names { { "Name1", "Name 2" } };
        // equivalent to
        var names = new Names();
        names.Add("Name1", "Name 2");
    }
}

public class Names : IEnumerable
{
    Collection<string> _myCollection = new Collection<string>();
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return this._myCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public void Add(params string[] names) {
      foreach (var name in names)
         this._myCollection.Add(name);
    }
}
```